# Understanding a paper: What is the meaning of $b_0$?

Tags: optics, boundary-conditions, diffraction

I am looking at [this paper](http://www.mcgrating.com/references/ref02.pdf) (Multicoated gratings, J. Opt. Soc. Am.,  1981) and I am getting confused around equation 22.  I do not completely understand where he comes up with the equation

$$\xi^j_q=b_q^j(R^{-1}V_q^j)\qquad \text{(22)}$$

And then what is the meaning of the $b^{j+1}$.  I initially thought they were the eigenvalues of the T matrix he defines, but all he says is that it is a vector of components $b^q_j$.

This includes the $\bf b^0$ and $\bf b^{Q+1}$ which I do not see how they are vectors?

Comment: It is said (just before $(22)$) that the $\xi^j_q$ are proportional to the eigenvectors $R^{-1}V_q^j$
So $b_q^j$ is just the ratio (which is different for each $j$ and $q$), between the two terms ,that is : $$\xi^j_q=b_q^j(R^{-1}V_q^j)$$
$\bf b^j$ is the vector with coordinates $b_q^j$, $q = 1,2,....+\infty$ (see just after $(23)$

Answer (score 1):

The formal structure shows, that the matrix in brackets is of same dimension as the matrix $\xi^j_q$. Therefore $b_q^j$ is just a *proportionality constant*. The coatings/media of the optical structure are labeled by index $j$.
$$\xi^j_q=b_q^j(R^{-1}V_q^j)\qquad \text{(22)}$$

> And then what is the meaning of the $\bf b^{j+1}$?

The set of equations (22) is expressed in equation (23). By by introducing a new vector
$$\bf{b^j}=
\begin{pmatrix}
b^j_1\\
b^j_2\\
\dots\\
b^j_\infty
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you get rid of index q. Where the index $j$ labels the medium of the coating. So you got some vector description of each coating layer $j$. Citing the paper

> The problem reduces now to the search for vectors $\bf b^j$ in each medium.

Comment: Any idea on how to solve for the $\mathbf b^j$

Comment: [Linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_equation), since equation (23) is of form $$\bf{\xi}=M\quad\bf{b^j}$$Take inverse $M^{-1}$

Comment: Equation 24, has $b^j$ in both sides of the equation.  Do I want equation 23 and actually solve for the $\xi$

Comment: You are correct. I had to write (23). This was my first thought.

Comment: Not a problem.  Any chance you understand what the author says in 4A about the matrix sizes that reduces equation 28 to 4N+2 equations with that many unknowns?

Comment: ???????????????